# How to display that data was unavaible during some time in a Chart.js (or any other library's) timeline graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js, timeline

I render a **chart**/line **graph** with **Chart.js** where a **ping** of a server throughout the last month is displayed (a cloud function is ran every hour and the data gets send to a time series database). But accidents happen, and the server is sometimes unreachable. For those times I save the ping as -1. Also sometimes the data is just missing. I need to display those two cases differently. Like, is there any way, to for example color a part of the graph red when the server was offline and with grey when the data is missing? Preferably using Chart.js, but you can suggest any other JavaScript library.

*Thank you so much.*

Answer (score 0):

With the new version 3 of chartjs which is releasing soon you can set the backgroundColor of the points like this:

```
backgroundColor: (context) => {return context.dataPoint?.y > 5 ? "green" : "red"}
```

And then you will have to put the right logic and values there. If you want the line also in different colors you will need to write a custom plugin for that since it is not supported by the default lib

Working example of points: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/8bkz96cd/7/

Comment: Thanks, seems like the most I can do is render the line with a red color when the ping is -1